# How to filter the object using lodash or javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, lodash

I am getting object like this from the Server,

```js
var data = {
  test1: {
    documents: []
  },
  test2: {
    documents: [{
      vId: 'sdfas23',
      TypeId: '81',
      isDeleted: false
    }],
    answer: true
  },
  test3: {
    documents: [{
      vId: 'H1mJinyI',
      TypeId: '82',
      isDeleted: false
    }],
    answer: true
  }
}
```

i want to filter the typeId from the object, The Result i am Expecting is

```
[81,82]
```

can anybody help on this.

Comment: How far did you get when you attempted to write the relevant code? Where did you get stuck? What went wrong?

Comment: I once encountered a similar use-case and i used lodash `map()`. 
Read the cocs here: https://lodash.com/docs#map

Answer (score 3):

In case you have only one or zero objects in `documents` like in your example you can use `reduce()` with `Object.keys()`

```js
var data = {"test1":{"documents":[]},"test2":{"documents":[{"vId":"sdfas23","TypeId":"81","isDeleted":false}],"answer":true},"test3":{"documents":[{"vId":"H1mJinyI","TypeId":"82","isDeleted":false}],"answer":true}}

var result = Object.keys(data).reduce(function(a, e) {
  if (data[e].documents[0]) a.push(data[e].documents[0].TypeId);
  return a;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

For multiple objects in `documents` array you can add `forEach` loop to previous code so you get this (there are two objects in `test3.documents`)

```js
var data = {"test1":{"documents":[]},"test2":{"documents":[{"vId":"sdfas23","TypeId":"81","isDeleted":false}],"answer":true},"test3":{"documents":[{"vId":"H1mJinyI","TypeId":"82","isDeleted":false},{"vId":"Random","TypeId":"100","isDeleted":false}],"answer":true}}

var result = Object.keys(data).reduce(function(a, e) {
  if (data[e].documents.length) data[e].documents.forEach(function(p) {
    a.push(p.TypeId);
  });
  return a;
}, [])

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @RIYAJ KHAN Thanks.

Comment: Why have you added check for length for forEach?

Comment: @Rajesh length check is added to eliminate elements with ``documents = []`` which is true for ``data.test1.documents``

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with just a single line of code:

```
_.map(_.flatten(_.map(_.values(data), 'documents')), 'TypeId');
```

This will produce:

```
["81", "82"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

1. Get access to every object in a way, you can use same expression for it. [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) will help you get keys of an object and you can use `data[key]` to get object.
2. Now once we have object, we know where to look i.e. `obj.documents`. Now documents is an array and we need to get `TypeId` in every object in it. For this, you can have an array and manually push value in it or you can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
3. Now if you use `.map`, it will return an array for every object. So you will have to use `array.concat` to append it to same function. But if you use `.push`, then skip this step.

#### For..in + .map + .concat

```js
var data={test1:{documents:[]},test2:{documents:[{vId:"sdfas23",TypeId:"81",isDeleted:!1}],answer:!0},test3:{documents:[{vId:"H1mJinyI",TypeId:"82",isDeleted:!1}],answer:!0}};

var r = [];
for(var k in data){
  r = r.concat(data[k].documents.map(function(o){return o.TypeId}));
}

console.log(r)
```

Comment: @Downvoter, please comment what is missing in the answer.

Comment: Am not the downvoter, i know you have a good solution, but please include some explanations so beginners and others will benefit from this good answer.

Comment: @hamism I have updated the answer. Hope it explains properly.

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the expected result, though not sure will you be happy with it

```
var data=  { 
    test1: { documents: [] },
    test2: { documents: [{ vId: 'sdfas23',
          TypeId: '81',
          isDeleted: false }], answer: true },
    test3:
     { documents:
        [{ vId: 'H1mJinyI',
          TypeId: '82',
          isDeleted: false }],
       answer: true } 
} 

function getIds(array) {
    var ret = [];
    for (key in data) {
        for (key2 in data[key].documents) {
            ret.push(data[key].documents[key2].TypeId)
         }
    }
    return ret
}

console.log(getIds(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data).map(function(val, key) {    
    return data[val].documents[0] ? data[val].documents[0].TypeId : '';    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If property "documents" always have only one object, just use `_.compact(_.map(data, 'documents[0].TypeId'));`

If property "documents" have many objects, use `_.flatten(_.map(data, (item) => _.map(item.documents, 'TypeId')));`

Example - https://jsfiddle.net/qvkctvho/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here is another simplified version of the previous answers(no **reduce** and **fancy** stuff only map ) :

```
var data=  { test1: { documents: [] },
             test2: { documents: [{ vId: 'sdfas23', TypeId: '81', isDeleted: false },{ vId: 'sdfas23', TypeId: '85', isDeleted: false }], answer: true },
             test3: { documents: [{ vId: 'H1mJinyI', TypeId: '82', isDeleted: false }], answer: true } 
};

var getTypeIds = function(data){
    var ids = [];
   // get object keys in this case : test1,test2,test3
    Object.keys(data).map(function(key){        
        // loop through each document attribute and extract TypeId attributes
        data[key].documents.map(function(item){                                                
                                    ids.push(item.TypeId);                                    
                                });


    })
    return ids;   
}

console.log(getTypeIds(data)); // [ '81', '85', '82' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use _.map function of lodash to get the result you want. Here is the sample code -

```
var result = _.map(data, function(v,i){
    if(_.isArray(v.documents)) {
        return v.documents[0].TypeId
    }

    return ''
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this in lodash is by using [flatMap()](https://lodash.com/docs#flatMap) to get a flattened array of `documents` and [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map) to get all `TypeId`.

```
var result = _(data)
.flatMap('documents')
.map('TypeId')
.value();
```

```js
var data = {
  test1: {
    documents: []
  },
  test2: {
    documents: [{
      vId: 'sdfas23',
      TypeId: '81',
      isDeleted: false
    }],
    answer: true
  },
  test3: {
    documents: [{
      vId: 'H1mJinyI',
      TypeId: '82',
      isDeleted: false
    }],
    answer: true
  }
};

var result = _(data)
.flatMap('documents')
.map('TypeId')
.value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

A plain JS solution with ES6 should be something like this:

```
var result = Object.keys(data) // get keys as reference when mapping
.map(v => data[v].documents || []) // get all documents
.reduce((x, y) => x.concat(y)) // flatten
.map(v => v.TypeId); // get TypeId
```

```js
var data = {
  test1: {
    documents: []
  },
  test2: {
    documents: [{
      vId: 'sdfas23',
      TypeId: '81',
      isDeleted: false
    }],
    answer: true
  },
  test3: {
    documents: [{
      vId: 'H1mJinyI',
      TypeId: '82',
      isDeleted: false
    }],
    answer: true
  }
};

var result = Object.keys(data)
.map(v => data[v].documents || [])
.reduce((x, y) => x.concat(y))
.map(v => v.TypeId);

console.log(result);
```